# My computer's display goes black after a while of use, but it isn't the display. Is the issue my motherboard, or my GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express, amd-graphics-card

For reference, I am running Linux on my PC, but I know the issue isn't a software one, since I run Linux on all my machines and have on this one for a while, and this issue is relatively recent, so it can't be Linux itself.

I suspect the problem may be with the motherboard, but I am unsure. I suspect this because one of the two PCIe slots on the motherboard is bent, probably during transit (traveled with my PC recently). I tried using the other slot for the GPU, thinking that that might fix it, but the problem still occurred within the next 24 hours. If it is the motherboard, I assume the problem would have to be with the PCIe bus itself, but again, I don't know enough to be sure.

I'm hoping the issue is with the motherboard, since that would be easier to replace money-wise.

The GPU is new (purchased March 2020), and is an AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT and worked perfectly until I traveled with the machine, further leading me to the above conclusion about the motherboard.

This is a really important issue for me, since the computer is question is needed for both gaming and schoolwork for the upcoming semester.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know too little about Linux to go into specifics, but on Windows, there's a way to do certain tasks from a different computer on the network (obviously only with the user name and password for the original computer). Tasklist and taskkill are examples of tasks that can be executed on a remote computer. I've used this in the past to diagnose what's going on on a computer that isn't responding anymore. Somewhere there's probably a Linux equivalent that might help you.

Comment: can u try the gpu in another motherboard?

Comment: Since you never had this issue before the motherboard got damaged, it seems clear to me that this is the problem, but I think you should also check the GPU on another PC to be sure that it works as it should